Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available
I'm a kafka beginner and I am doing a course on it. Was following along and had to create a producer demo file but I keep getting this error:
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Node may not be available.
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 disconnected.

Here is my code:
package io.conduktor.demos.kafka;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.Field;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerDemo {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProducerDemo.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Hello World!");

        //create Producer Properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        //connect to Localhost
        properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

        //connect to Conduktor playground
        //properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "cluster.playground.cdkt.io:9092");
        //properties.setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL");
        //properties.setProperty("sasl.jaas.config", "org.apache.kafka...");
        //properties.setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "PLAIN");

        //set producer properties
        properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
        properties.setProperty("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());

        //create the Producer
        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

        //create a producer Record
        ProducerRecord<String, String> producerRecord =
                new ProducerRecord<>("demo_java","hello world");

        //send data
        producer.send(producerRecord);

        //tell the producer to send all data and block until done --synchronous
        producer.flush();

        //flush and close the producer
        producer.close();

    }
}

I have tried changing the hostports, node ID's, check for firewalls(all inactive), there's zero security and I can't wrap my head around fixing it.
Here is the connection:
bartello@LAPTOP-K0A7F8UD:~$ kafka-topics.sh --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic demo_java
Topic: demo_java        TopicId: uD7yPEAnQ6iWmQtqbJ-GCg PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
        Topic: demo_java        Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1

Update:
I figured it out! Just had to change all localhosts to [::1] so it would connect to ipv6 instead of ipv4, I don't fully understand but it works now.

Can you verify the broker is actually running on port 9092 if you've changed it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
